# How to create triggers which accepts external parameters in SQL Server?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Is it possible to write a trigger which accepts external parameters?

The main reason of this is, I am restricted to connect to the database using only **ONE** database user. Now I am developing a database application and have created triggers for each individual tables to store the history.

While storing the history data, I want to store the **Application User Name** who has done the `Insert`, `Update` or `Delete`. I thought to use `User_Name()` but came to know that, it only returns the database user, **NOT** the application user.

Therefore, I am looking for some suggestions on creating triggers with external parameters so that I can pass the application user's id to this trigger. Think I have clearly explained my needs. Thanks in advance !

**Edit**
External parameter should be something similar to stored procedure parameters where we can pass value

**Edit2**
May be my description is not clear enough. So I am giving you an example.
The Web Application I am developing is Account Related. So to keep track of data changes in required. For example, Account personnel can change employee's Salary and Commission info. If a wrong info is entered/updated then the overall financial outcome will have large negative impact. Now in the system, an user login to the system using userid & password and then do some changes in employee information. In this stage, I want to keep the track that, who has changed the employee information, when did the changes and the values before the change is done and value after the change is completed. So that, in future if any thing goes wrong, I can find out the user who did the mistake with PROOF.
Not necessarily it should be done using trigger but any other alternative is also welcome.

Comment: What is the "application user's ID"? Is it a SQL login, a Windows account or something else? Does SYSTEM_USER return what you want or not?

Comment: Where do you get the application user from? Why can't you look up the application user inside the trigger?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pass a variable into a trigger](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2646547/pass-a-variable-into-a-trigger) try using `CONTEXT_INFO()`, see the link for answers using this.

Comment: "Application User ID" is the login id an user will use to login to system this is stored in the database table.

Comment: @V.P.Verma You still need to be more precise, it isn't clear if the login is a SQL Server login, a Windows account or something managed entirely within your application. If it's SQL or Windows, then SYSTEM_USER will return it; if it's something internal to your application, then you will need to follow one of the other suggestions here (the one above from KM about using context_info is an exact match for your question).

Comment: Sorry for being late and confusing :( The login system I mentioned is entirely within my application. More precisely, I am using UserID: A & Password: B to connect to the database (this is the restriction i mentioned in my question and this is SQL Server login info). When the database connection is made, i am using the UserID: X & Password: Y to check user entry in the application (X & Y is managed in my system). My goal is to save the X in database history table. I will get back to you after trying KM's solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to re-engineer your approach.  There is no way for a database to *just know* anything about your application user information.  And, no, you can't pass parameters to triggers.  But you can reference your own tables from withing triggers, so there is an approach...

When you connect to the database, each connection gets it's own process id.  You can get at this through @@spid.

So, when your trigger fires you can use that to know which connection caused the change.

You could have 100 concurrent connections using the same database login, and each would have it's own @@spid value.

For that to be useful to you, however, you need to prepare all of your connections.  Every time a connection is made, your application should write to a table to record what application use is using that @@spid.

Maybe something as simple as...

```
CREATE TABLE
  map_spid_application_user (
    spid          BIGINT,
    application   VARCHAR(128),
    user          VARCHAR(128),
    PRIMARY KEY (spid)
  )
```

Then, on every connection, run something like this (maybe through a stored procedure)...

```
DELETE map_spid_application_user WHERE spid = @@spid

INSERT INTO map_spid_application_user SELECT @@spid, 'myApp', 'myUser'
```

Then, in your trigger, you can reference/join on this table to find out who the @@spid refers to.

You can also get more intelligent, and use a similar approach to keep a permanent record of what users connected, as what spid.  The current user for any spid will always be the one with the most recent connection datetime.

You can do almost anything you like then.  Because you're creating all the information, and not relying on the database to *just know* anything other than the @@spid.

Answer (score 1):

Store the user name in each table and pass it in as a parameter during data changes. From there, the trigger can archive the data to another table(s).

Comment: "Store the user name in each table and pass it in as a parameter during data changes" I am a bit confused about what you are trying to say. :(

Answer (score 1):

In your place I will use this example and if in yor database somebody will do event update or select you will be able add some information this what you want.

Example table:

```
CREATE TABLE RAF1
(
strona NUMBER,
nazwa VARCHAR2(40)
);
```

Example Trigger(this trigger will always if you will put nazw='same' write nazwa='roland' it`s connected to this table you can edit this example.

```
create or replace TRIGGER sam 
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF nazwa
 ON RAF1 FOR EACH ROW WHEN (new.nazwa = 'same')
 BEGIN :new.nazwa := 'ronald'; END
```

Comment: This question is for SQL-Server, not Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

I've done what you described. I can't say I was happy with the result because the solution can be rather brittle - breaking when something strange like connection sharing happens. It also just feels wrong, but try it if you like.

1. On the application side, stuff the username into the ConnectionString's AppName property.
2. In the trigger, reference the App_Name() function.

Again, this will do what you ask, but I don't recommend it. Better to just manage audit info  as part of the basic insert/update stuff from the client or through stored procedures.

Answer (score 0):

Since triggers are by design **niladic** modules, meaning they don't support parameters. One techique to pass information between an outer level and a niladic module is to use either context info or session context.

```
Declare @mycontextinfo AS VARBINARY(128) = CAST('Application User Name' AS VARBINARY(128))
SET CONTEXT_INFO @mycontextinfo;
```

You can read you context info from anywhere in your session, including triggers as follows:

```
SELECT CAST(CONTEXT_INFO() AS VARCHAR(128)) AS mycontextinfo;
```

another most sophisticated way is using Session context;

```
EXEC sys.sp_set_Session_context @key = 'ApplicationUser', @value = 'XXX', @read_only = 1;
```

Then when you need to read the value from anywhere in your session, you use the following code:

```
SELECT SESSION_CONTEXT('ApplicationUser') AS [USER]
```

**Keep in mind this was added in SQL Server 2016.**