# How to store UserName who is Updating the value of a table in For Update Trigger?

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, sql-server-2012

In my web application, am creating a log process. I have created an update trigger, its working perfectly but I need to know who updated this data i.e the user who performed this action.

I have googled it and asking to use context_info. What does it mean?

**How to store this information in trigger table?**

This is my procedure.. i have used your concept..

```
ALTER Procedure [dbo].[MIS_CompOffDate]   
(  
@EmpId nvarchar(20), 

@UserName nvarchar(50),

@ActualDate datetime,

@DayName nvarchar(20),

@CompOffDate datetime 

)  

As

Begin 

DECLARE @UserNameConverted VARBINARY(128) = CONVERT(VARBINARY(128), @EmpId);

SET CONTEXT_INFO @UserNameConverted;  

INSERT INTO MIS_BM_CompOff values(@EmpId, @UserName, @ActualDate, @DayName, @CompOffDate)

End
```

In the empid-the user's empid is there...

Comment: Which user ? SqlServer user ? Web authenticated user ? Are they the same, or not ?

Comment: Unless it's a database user doing the updating, why don't you not use triggers, and just have the application do that update?

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus Web authenticated user, no they are not same

Comment: So no way to get them with a trigger (I would say).

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus, then how to achieve this concept any suggestion..

Comment: What do you need ? A modifiedBy on each row ? A separated log table ? Anyhow, you'll have to do this, as stated by Andrew Barber, at application level, which is the only one to know the users...

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus, So how to achieve that modifieldBy (name) on each row? how to achieve this without triggers

Comment: @AndrewBarber, its possible to aachiev this by using context_info?

Comment: A similar question was posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2646547/pass-a-variable-into-a-trigger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done following the steps below:

1. Pass to your update function/procedure the user ID or name
2. In the update function/procedure set the user ID or name as shared
   variable using [SET CONTEXT_INFO](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187768.aspx) like this:

   ```
   SET CONTEXT_INFO @UserID
   ```
3. In your trigger, extract the ID using [CONTEXT_INFO()](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180125.aspx) function:

   ```
   DECLARE @UserID BIGINT = COALESCE(CAST(CAST(CONTEXT_INFO() AS BINARY(8)) AS INT),0)
   ```

Comment: I guess you are doing something wrong. Do you follow the steps? What is the error you are getting?

Comment: SET CONTEXT_INFO option requires varbinary (128) NOT NULL parameter. This was my error. I am passing the value of userid from c# and trying to store UserId(EmpId of varchar datatype) in procedure. I have used the above coding only set context_info @userid.

Comment: @user2941383 The error tells that you are trying to set NULL value as CONTEXT_INFO. So, the `@UserID` is not initialized. Check this: `DECLARE @UserID BIGINT = 1001;

SET CONTEXT_INFO @UserID;

SELECT COALESCE(CAST(CAST(CONTEXT_INFO() AS BINARY(8)) AS INT),0);
`

Comment: The UserId(Empid) is of varchar type you are directly assigning the value instead i need to get from my c# code behind i.e assign in the procedure parameter..

Comment: Check if you are passing it correctly. Anyway, you can store and text values as follows: `DECLARE @UserName VARCHAR(128) ='user2941383';
DECLARE @UserNameConverted VARBINARY(128) = CONVERT(VARBINARY(128), @UserName);
SET CONTEXT_INFO  @UserNameConverted;
SELECT CAST(CAST(CONTEXT_INFO() AS VARBINARY(128)) AS VARCHAR(128));
`

Comment: SELECT CAST(CAST(CONTEXT_INFO() AS VARBINARY(128)) AS VARCHAR(128));. This line i have to use in trigger to get the username from the procedure . Is it correct.

Comment: The output is showing some other value.. I inserted with userid EC2911 but in the trigger table table output it is showing as userid as'e'..I am inserting from the front end c#

Comment: Try to execute the UPDATE from the SQL Management Studio using some "sample" id. If in the trigger table you are getting the correct result, the issue is in the C# code, otherwise in the SQL. Can you do this?

Comment: I tried from sql management studio, but again it showing the result as same. I insert the value with empid of EC2911. In the trigger table it storing only the first letter 'E' only. i want to store the empid full.. Any suggestion

Comment: I can not tell in this way. Could you post the SQL statement as EDIT to your question?

Comment: In the trigger am using this line to get the UserId: @UserName = CAST(CAST(CONTEXT_INFO() AS VARBINARY(128)) AS VARCHAR(128))

Comment: The userid is storing in the format of E C 2 9 1 1.. While retrieving the 'E' letter alone getting retrieved from that context_info(). How to retrieve that userid value fully

Comment: This is caused because the `@EmpId` is of type `NVARCHAR`. You should make the cast to `NVARCHAR` too and everything is going to work :) I mean in your trigger - the cast should be to `NVARCHAR` too.

Comment: I am confused.. in the code were to make that conversion.. Can you  post the edited code.Thanks for replying...

Comment: I tried but not getting,Can you post how to make cast of nvarchar in the trigger..Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use trigger to insert `SYSTEM_USER` or `USER_NAME()` into a table .
So any action that fire your trigger will have the login name or username of the person does that action.
this is inside database . But for web application you can save login name information for the person who acting, in a variable after any successful login and in any update use stored procedure and one of the requested parameters should be that login parameter.

Comment: I have tried this and it will store the database user name alone i need web application user who did update operation on my table

Comment: Oh this is inside database . But for web you can save login name information for the person who acting, in a variable after any successful login and in any update use stored procedure and one of the requested parameters should be that login parameter.

Comment: Okay am storing username in procedure parameter.How to get that login parameter within trigger function and store i trigger table

Comment: In this method there is no need of trigger and stored procedure do this. trigger is for internal usage.

Answer (score 2):

I had this same problem, and used a few answers across SO to solve this problem. I made a stored procedure `sp_SetConnectionUsername` to save the username, and a function `f_GetConnectionUsername` that could be used within triggers to retrieve the username. Because `CONTEXT_INFO` stores the data in binary, there is a little finessing that needs to happen to get the varchar data back out of it. And please note that the limit of `CONTEXT_INFO` is 128 bytes (so 128 characters).

Here is the stored procedure that is called upon opening the connection from an application to set the username:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_SetConnectionUsername]
    @username varchar(128)
AS
BEGIN
    -- Convert username varchar into binary
    DECLARE @binaryUsername varbinary(128)
    SET @binaryUsername = CAST(@username as varbinary(128))
    SET CONTEXT_INFO @binaryUsername
END
```

And here is the function that is called in triggers to retrieve the username:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[f_GetConnectionUsername]()
RETURNS varchar(128)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @username varchar(128)

    -- Get binary from CONTEXT_INFO, convert to varchar, then remove all Char(0) 
    -- empty characters from it (these are used as spacing in binary). Otherwise,
    -- if CONTEXT_INFO has not been set, return the SQL Server username.
    IF CONTEXT_INFO() IS NOT NULL
        SET @username = REPLACE((select cast(CONTEXT_INFO() as varchar(128))) COLLATE 
            Latin1_General_BIN, CHAR(0), '')
    ELSE
        SET @username = SYSTEM_USER

    RETURN @username
END
```

Hope that can help someone.

Comment: I was looking for an alternative for [SESSION_CONTEXT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt590806.aspx), which is not available in SQL Server 2012. This works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Trigger will only know about the changes you made to the table, it won't know about information external to the actual inserts/updates, etc.

You will be better off to handle it from your application and passing the information about the updating user together with other information.